# select query writing in android development

Tags: java, android

Please help me in writing the query in android development

```
"SELECT * FROM '" + pendingpost_tb + "'" +
" where '" + AppUtil.post_type + "'" + "=history " +
" order by '" + AppUtil.datetime + "'" + " DESC"
```

i want the list of AppUtil.post_type in desc order by date and time ,datetime i have fetched form the database .

Comment: What's the outcome of your current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something is wrong with your statement.
I think that is a working statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + pendingpost_tb +
" where " + AppUtil.post_type +  "='history'" +
" order by " + AppUtil.datetime + " DESC"
```

are you sure that AppUtil.datetime is your column name?

Furthermore it is better to use PreparedStatments. I am not realy sure if PreparedStatement is available for android but there must be something which is equivalent to it.

Comment: AppUtil.datetime is the data which i get from the sqlite database .we want to make it descending from the DATE wise

Comment: i tried above but getting this error   "01-29 20:07:11.702: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Planner.postplanner/com.Planner.postplanner.Welcome_page}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM pendingpost_tbwhere posttype='history' order by datetime DESC
"

Comment: there is a space between "pendingpost_tb" and "where"